# problems with working compile and multiprocessing at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, multiprocessing

i work in VSCode and when I run this file:

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def mp_setup_and_run(processes_num, *args):
    processes = {}

    for i in range(processes_num):
        processes[i] = Process(
            target=function_example,
            args=args,
            daemon=True,)

        processes[i].start()

    for i in range(processes_num):
        processes[i].join()


def function_example(*data):
    print(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    compiled = compile("z**2 + c", "<string>", "eval")

    mp_setup_and_run(3, compiled)
```

I get an exception/s:

```
PS C:\Python\projects\mondebrot_painter>  cd 'c:\Python\projects\mondebrot_painter'; & 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' 'c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher' '51560' '--' 'c:\Python\projects\mondebrot_painter\test.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>       
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Python\projects\mondebrot_painter\test.py", line 45, in <module>
    result = mp_setup_and_run(3, compiled)
  File "c:\Python\projects\mondebrot_painter\test.py", line 19, in mp_setup_and_run
    processes[i].start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 326, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'code' object
```

and the debugger redirects me to the `<string>` file:

```
LOAD_CONST(0), LOAD_CONST(None), IMPORT_NAME(sys), STORE_NAME(sys), LOAD_NAME(sys.path), LOAD_METHOD(insert), LOAD_CONST(0), LOAD_CONST('c:\\Users\\ASUS\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.5.80290\\pythonFiles\\lib\\python\\debugpy\\no_wheels\\debugpy\\_vendored\\pydevd'), CALL_METHOD{2}, POP_TOP, LOAD_CONST(0), LOAD_CONST(None), IMPORT_NAME(pydevd), STORE_NAME(pydevd), LOAD_CONST('http_json'), LOAD_NAME(pydevd.PydevdCustomization), STORE_ATTR(DEFAULT_PROTOCOL), LOAD_NAME(pydevd.settrace), LOAD_CONST('127.0.0.1'), LOAD_CONST(51592), LOAD_CONST(False), LOAD_CONST(False), LOAD_CONST(True), LOAD_CONST(None), LOAD_CONST('92e8bb604eeece436b2401def85a7ab95455e6c26fd9d660cb8175e691d71bd0'), LOAD_CONST('127.0.0.1'), LOAD_CONST('92e8bb604eeece436b2401def85a7ab95455e6c26fd9d660cb8175e691d71bd0'), LOAD_CONST(True), LOAD_CONST(True), LOAD_CONST(51592), LOAD_CONST(9040), LOAD_CONST(False), LOAD_CONST(('client', 'client-access-token', 'json-dap-http', 'multiprocess', 'port', 'ppid', 'server')), BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP{7}, LOAD_CONST(('host', 'port', 'suspend', 'trace_only_current_thread', 'patch_multiprocessing', 'access_token', 'client_access_token', '__setup_holder__')), CALL_FUNCTION_KW{8}, POP_TOP, LOAD_CONST(0), LOAD_CONST(('spawn_main',)), IMPORT_NAME(multiprocessing.spawn), IMPORT_FROM(spawn_main), STORE_NAME(spawn_main), POP_TOP, LOAD_NAME(spawn_main), LOAD_CONST(9040), LOAD_CONST(892), LOAD_CONST(('parent_pid', 'pipe_handle')), CALL_FUNCTION_KW{2}, POP_TOP, return None
```

if I run the program from the console, I get this message:

```
C:\Python\projects\mondebrot_painter>python set_generator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "set_generator.py", line 121, in <module>
    set_ = mp_setup_and_run(senter, length, quality, processes_num, max_iter, compiled, mode)
  File "set_generator.py", line 86, in mp_setup_and_run
    processes[i].start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 326, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'code' object

C:\Python\projects\mondebrot_painter>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 107, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access Denied
```

I am somewhat lost and don’t understand what is happening and why I can't pass compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simplify away the `multiprocessing` code and just use this from the console, you'll see the `TypeError` you are getting:

```
$ python
...
>>> compiled = compile("z**2 + c", "<string>", "eval")
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(compiled)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't pickle code objects
```

This makes sense because [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) tells us that `pickle` [can handle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> - `None`, `True`, and `False`
> - integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers
> - strings, bytes, bytearrays
> - tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable objects
> - functions defined at the top level of a module (using def, not lambda)
> - built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> - classes that are defined at the top level of a module
> - instances of such classes whose `__dict__` or the result of calling `__getstate__()` is picklable (see section Pickling Class Instances for details).

and `compiled` is not one of these.<sup>1</sup>

What's not said here, but is crucial to know, is that the `multiprocessing` module *must* be able to use the `pickle` code to serialize objects, so as to send them from one Python process to another.  Since your `compiled` expression is not serializable, it *cannot* be sent from one Python process to another.

**The trick is to serialize the expression, not the compiled expression.**  That is, instead of:

```
mp_setup_and_run(3, compiled)
```

use:

```
mp_setup_and_run(3, "z**2 + c")
```

Then, in `mp_setup_and_run`, have it pass the *expression* to the function.  Have each function make *its own* call to `compile`.  You'll do three separate `compile`s, in your three separate processes that run with the multiprocessing module, but that's OK.

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, the documentation also says:

> Attempts to pickle unpicklable objects will raise the `PicklingError` exception

when you and I both got `TypeError` instead.  But this is the reason for the `TypeError`.

Comment: Do you suggest calling compile in ```function_example``` every time?

Comment: Call it as few times as possible: once per process, for instance.